# How can I export BCD GUID identifier and description to text file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, bcdedit

I'm using a dual bool Windows machine with different versions of Windows on it (8.1 and 10) and I need a way of noting each installs unique GUID identifier.

Currently I can only export the entire bcdedit which is not what I'm after, how can I export the GUID identifiers and the descriptions ONLY into a txt file?

[image]

Comment: `bcdedit /enum|findstr /C:"identifier" /C:"description"`

Comment: That's almost perfect @Squashman, thank you - any way I can remove the GUID and Windows Boot Manager entries that are always the top two lines?

Comment: Use another PIPE to `FINDSTR` to exclude those entries.

Comment: You need to be very clear up front what your intended output needs to be. Sometimes it could mean a complete rewrite of the code which wastes peoples valuable time that they are using to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Squashman answered in comments the simplest way to get your target(s) is

```
c:\Windows\System32\bcdedit.exe /enum |findstr "den des"
identifier              {bootmgr}
description             Windows Boot Manager
identifier              {current}
description             Windows 10
identifier              {cace6f08-28f0-11eb-b3c4-4c72b9b04518}
description             Windows 10
```

You asked how to remove top two entries, so use more for less :-)

```
c:\Windows\System32\bcdedit.exe /enum |findstr "den des" |more +2
identifier              {current}
description             Windows 10
identifier              {cace6f08-28f0-11eb-b3c4-4c72b9b04518}
description             Windows 10
```

and if your next question is 2+2 use 4

`c:\Windows\System32\bcdedit.exe /enum |findstr "den des" |more +4 >c:\output.txt`

the output is sent to a file which because you are running in an unknown but  likely protected zone I simply sent to the c:\ root directory, change to the temporary folder or other desired location. You can check the output with type.

```
C:\Windows\system32>type c:\output.txt
identifier              {cace6f08-28f0-11eb-b3c4-4c72b9b04518}
description             Windows 10
```

and

`For /F "Tokens=2*" %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe "e" c:\output.txt') Do @echo %~G %~H >c:\out2.txt`

will then return using type

```
C:\Windows\system32>type c:\out2.txt
{cace6f08-28f0-11eb-b3c4-4c72b9b04518}
Windows 10
```

Remember for %%var if you are adding together as a batch file:-

RunMe.cmd (MUST BE run as administrator, otherwise you will see that bcedit access denied will result in "The system cannot find the file specified.")

```
@echo off
c:\Windows\System32\bcdedit.exe /enum |findstr "den des" |more +4>"%temp%\tempout.txt"
if exist "%temp%\tempout2.txt" del "%temp%\tempout2.txt"
For /F "Tokens=2*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe "e" "%temp%\tempout.txt"') Do @echo %%~G %%~H >>"%temp%\tempout2.txt"
type "%temp%\tempout2.txt"
```

```
c:\Windows\System32>RunMe.cmd
{cace6f08-28f0-11eb-b3c4-4c72b9b04518}
Windows 10
```

Note the above result depends on 6 simple entries from my tests and `more +4` removes the first 4 it is not a robust solution to deal with varying number of lines output from bcedit.exe. so YMMV

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much @K J , greatly appreciated - if you have a lil extra way to get rid of the "identifier" and "description" and those large gaps, I'd be in your debt even more so ^^;.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me @K J - super appreciated!

For /F "Tokens=2*" %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe "e" \output.txt') Do @echo %~G %~H >c:\out2.txt 

returns... FINDSTR: Cannot open \output.txt

and the RunMe.cmd when put in a batch file returns the results but with the identifier, description and gaps.